# Unable to send values to textbox in new window through sendkeys

Tags: java, selenium, click, sendkeys

Current window contains some elements.When i give some value in textbox and click on enter a new dialog window will be opened.In this i need to give values to few textboxes and close the window.But i am unable to send the values to textbox.Below are the scenarios i have tried.

1)Tried switching the window.But it is showing error as NoSuchelement exception.

2)Instead of switching window i have directly send the value to textbox.This time i didnot get Nosuchelemnt exception.Instead i am getting exception as element not interactable via keyboard.

3)Tried using Action class to send values.Getting MoveTargetOutofBoundsException.

4)Tried using JavaScriptExecutor to send the values.Script executed successfully.But not seeing any value is entered in the textbox while automating.Before entering value used scripts for focus and click.Still no use.

5)Tried whether element is displayed or not by isdisplayed.Element is not displayed.

6)Used explicit wait until element is visible.Getting time out exception.

Below are the scripts i have tried.

1. To click on element

   WebElement
   cgst=driver.findElement(By.xpath("elexpath"));
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("#gridbox >
   table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > div > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-
   child(18)")));
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

   ```
          jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", cgst);
   ```
2. To send values to textbox

   ```
     JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

     jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",cgst,"2");
   ```

3)To make the element visible and send the values

```
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; 
arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
         //String c="2";
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])",cgst,c);
```

4)To click on element using Actions class

```
Point point=cgst.getLocation();
    int xcord = point.getX();
    System.out.println("x" +xcord);
    int ycord = point.getY();
    System.out.println("y" +ycord);
    Actions a=new Actions(driver);
    a.moveByOffset(xcord, ycord).click().perform();
    System.out.println("clicked");
```

Most of the time i am getting element not displayed exception.Could anybody please help me? One more problem is I am unable to inspect the elements in the new window in IE.may be due to this I am unable to take the correct xpath of element?

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: auto; position: relative;"><img style="position: relative; display: none;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="hdr" width="100%" style="border: 0px solid gray; table-layout: fixed; width: 1830px;"><tbody><tr style="height: 15px; line-height: 15px;"><td style="width: 28px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">Sl No</td><td style="width: 98px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">A Code</td><td style="width: 198px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">A Name</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">RaiAmt</td><td style="width: 98px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">A Fee</td><td style="width: 98px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">G Amt</td><td style="width: 98px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">TD</td><td style="width: 148px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">Net</td><td style="width: 198px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">Se Bank</td><td style="width: 198px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">Pa Bank</td><td style="width: 198px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">ICode</td><td style="width: 198px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">A No</td><td style="width: 198px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">Bene</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">ser</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">st</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">np</td><td style="width: 48px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap;">Payment</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Cg Rate</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Cg Amt</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">S Rate</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">S Amt</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">I Rate</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Igst Amt</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Cg D Rate</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">C DRCR Amt</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">S DRCR Rate</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Sg DRCR Amt</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Ig DRCR Rate</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Ig DRCR Amt</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">G INNO</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">In Date</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">In Num</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Sc Value</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">HS</td><td style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">Debit/Credit Note</td></tr></tbody></table></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>

<div class="objbox" style="width: 100%; height: 247px; overflow: auto; position: relative; top: -63px;">
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; width: 1760px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="obj" style="width: 1760px; table-layout: fixed;"><tbody><tr>
<td align="right" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 28px;" title="1">1</td>
<td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 98px;" title="">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 198px;" title="">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 98px;" title="">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 98px;" title="">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="right" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 98px;" title="">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 148px;" title="">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 198px;" title="">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 198px;" title="">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 198px;" title="">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 198px;" title="">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 198px;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="center" bgcolor="" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 19px; height: 19px; width: 48px;">No</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td><td align="right" bgcolor="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

In the above html code after clicking on enter in the field
A Fee,new window will be opened.In the new window I need to click on Cg Rate and send the value to it.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: You are asking about application URL?

Comment: Yes, application url. Or share the html of the webelement you are trying to access